# Метод не работает корректно по истечении необходимого времени

Tags: java, многопоточность

Всем здравствуйте! Пытаюсь реализовать что-то на подобии простой фермы. Например растения можно посадить и собрать урожай, а у каждого растения есть время созревания. На текущий момент сложность заключается в том, что изменено не первое указанное для посадки поле, по прошествии нужного количества времени, а последнее указанное на момент этого времени. Приведу фрагмент кода, чтобы не засорять. Буду рад любой помощи и советам. Возможно я в целом мыслю неправильно и нужно реализовывать иначе.

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Player {
    final char SIGN_PLANT = 'X';
    final char SIGN_EMPTY = '_';
    final char SIGN_HARVEST = '0';
    private int cash;
    private char[] field;
    transient Scanner scanner;
    private Plant plant;

    Player(){
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        field = new char[8];
        cash = 100;
        plant = new Plant("Cucumber", 10, 15, 5);
    }

    void game(){
        initField(); //инициализация поля
        printField(); //печать поля

        while(true){
            toPlant(); //посадка
            if(isFieldFull()){
                System.out.println("JUST WAIT");
                break;
            }
            printField(); //печать поля
            execute(() -> getHarvest(), plant.getTime());
//            getHarvest();
        }
        printField();
    }

    void initField(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            field[i] = SIGN_EMPTY;
        }
    }

    void printField(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.print(field[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    int x;
    void toPlant(){

        do{
            System.out.println("Enter cell for your plant (1-8)");
            x = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            if(field[x] != SIGN_HARVEST && field[x] != SIGN_PLANT){
                if(cash >= plant.getSeedPrice()){
                    cash = cash - plant.getSeedPrice();
                    System.out.println("YOUR CASH IS " + cash);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("YOU HAVEN'T ENOUGH MONEY");
                }
            }
        } while (!isCellValid(x));
        field[x] = SIGN_PLANT;
    }

    public static void execute(Runnable task, long delaySec) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task.run();
                timer.cancel();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, delaySec*1000);
    }

    public void  getHarvest() {
//        Runnable task = () -> {
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(plant.getTime());
//                field[x] = SIGN_HARVEST;
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
//        };
//        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
//        thread.start();
        field[x] = SIGN_HARVEST;

//        field[x] = SIGN_HARVEST;
    }

    int y;
    void takeHarvest(){
        do{
            y = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if(field[y] == SIGN_HARVEST){
                    cash = cash + plant.getHarvestPrice();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("YOUR CASH IS " + cash);
        } while (!isCellValid(y));
        field[y] = SIGN_EMPTY;

    }

    boolean isCellValid(int x){
        if(x < 0 || x >= 8){
            System.out.println("OLOLO! YOU WERE ABROAD");
            return false;
        }
        return field[x] == SIGN_EMPTY;
    }

    boolean isFieldFull(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (field[i] == SIGN_EMPTY){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать более высокоуровневые решения. Благо в джаве их достаточно. А низкоуровневые оставьте для тех, кто специализируются на многопоточности. Таким образом, мы можете избежать большого количества багов, которые к тому же будет очень сложно воспроизвести и исправить.
Например, если вам необходимо отсроченное исполнение какой-либо задачи, можно использовать таймер. Если обернуть его в метод с удобным интерфейсом, то все очень сильно упростится. В данном случае есть само отсроченное действие и время , через которое необходимо его выполнить. Поэтому в методе будет 2 параметра.Первый принимает интерфейс Runnable. Это удобно, поскольку это функциональный интерфейс, следовательно, мы сможем передать лямбду. Второй аргумент - время в секундах, спустя которое и будет выполнено действие, переданное в лямбде.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Game {

    private final static String JSON_FILE_NAME = "json.txt";
    
    private final Scanner scanner;

    private final List<Plant> plants;
    private final List<Field> fields;

    private int cash;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        new Game(jsonToPlants(JSON_FILE_NAME), 100, 8).start();
    }

    private static List<Plant> jsonToPlants(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader(fileName), Plant[].class));
    }

    public Game(List<Plant> plants, int cash, int fieldSize) {
        this.cash = cash;
        this.plants = plants;
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.fields = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldSize; i++) fields.add(new Field());
    }

    public void start() {
        while (true) {
            out.println(fields);
            out.println("YOUR CASH : " + cash);
            out.println("Enter cell for your plant (1-8)");
            validField(scanner.nextLine()).ifPresent(fieldNumber -> {
                Field field = fields.get(fieldNumber);
                out.println("Enter plants number (1-" + plants.size() + ")");
                if (field.isEmpty()) {
                    validPlant(scanner.nextLine()).ifPresent(plantNumber -> {
                        Plant plant = plants.get(plantNumber);
                        execute(() -> getHarvest(fieldNumber), plant.getTime());
                        cash -= plant.getSeedPrice();
                        fields.set(fieldNumber, field.update(plant));
                    });
                } else {
                    cash += field.getHarvestPrice();
                    fields.set(fieldNumber, field.update());
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    private Optional<Integer> validPlant(String userInput) {
        try{
            Integer number = Integer.valueOf(userInput)-1;
            if (number < 0 || number >= plants.size()) return printAndReturnOptional("OLOLO! YOU WERE ABROAD");
            if (cash < plants.get(number).getSeedPrice()) return printAndReturnOptional("YOU HAVEN'T ENOUGH MONEY");
            return Optional.of(number);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return printAndReturnOptional("OLOLO! INCORRECT INPUT");
        }
    }
    
    private Optional<Integer> validField(String userInput) {
        try{
            Integer number = Integer.valueOf(userInput)-1;
            if (isFieldFull()) return printAndReturnOptional("JUST WAIT");
            if (number < 0 || number >= fields.size()) return printAndReturnOptional("OLOLO! YOU WERE ABROAD");
            if (fields.get(number).isFull()) return printAndReturnOptional("OLOLO! FIELD NOT EMPTY");
            return Optional.of(number);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return printAndReturnOptional("OLOLO! INCORRECT INPUT");
        }
    }
    
    private Optional printAndReturnOptional(String arg) {
        out.println(arg);
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public void  getHarvest(int fieldNumber) {
        fields.set(fieldNumber, fields.get(fieldNumber).update());
        out.println(fields);
    }

    private void execute(Runnable task, long delaySec) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task.run();
                timer.cancel();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, delaySec * 1000);
    }

    private boolean isFieldFull() {
        return !fields.stream().anyMatch(cell->cell.isEmpty());
    }

}

public class Field {
    
    private Sign sign;
    
    private Plant plant;
    
    public Field() {
        this.sign = Sign.EMPTY;
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return this.sign == Sign.EMPTY;
    }
    
    public boolean isFull(){
        return this.sign == Sign.PLANT;
    }
    
    public Field update(Plant plant) {
        this.sign = this.sign.update();
        this.plant = plant;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Field update() {
        return update(sign==Sign.EMPTY ? null : plant);
    }
    
    public int getHarvestPrice() {
        return plant.getHarvestPrice();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sign.toString();
    }
    
}

public class Plant {

    private String name;
    private int seedPrice;
    private int harvestPrice;
    private long time;
    
    public Plant() {
    }

    public Plant(String name, int seedPrice, int harvestPrice, long time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.seedPrice = seedPrice;
        this.harvestPrice = harvestPrice;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSeedPrice() {
        return seedPrice;
    }

    public void setSeedPrice(int seedPrice) {
        this.seedPrice = seedPrice;
    }

    public int getHarvestPrice() {
        return harvestPrice;
    }

    public void setHarvestPrice(int harvestPrice) {
        this.harvestPrice = harvestPrice;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Plant{"
                + "name='" + name + '\''
                + ", seedPrice=" + seedPrice
                + ", harvestPrice=" + harvestPrice
                + ", time=" + time
                + '}';
    }
    
}

public enum Sign {
    
    EMPTY("_"),
    PLANT("X"),//семена
    HARVEST("0");//урожай
    
    private final String symbol;

    private Sign(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return symbol;
    }
    
    public Sign update(){
        final Sign[] signs = Sign.values();
        return signs.length<=this.ordinal()+1 ? signs[0] : signs[this.ordinal()+1];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно очень крутой подход, который я раньше редко использовал
НО
к сожалению, результат работы остался прежним... возможно я что-то не так делаю? Позвольте я добавлю больше кода в свой изначальный фрагмент. Мб Вы увидите, что-то чего я не замечаю

Comment: @valerjan результат остался прежним потому, что в вашем коде проблема далеко не одна. вызов метода происходит совсем не там, где нужно. я постарался понять и исправить ваш код (хотя у меня он и не весь). следующая задача - попробуйте вынести функционал игрового поля в отдельный класс (в соответствии с принципом единой ответсвенности -> см.SOLID). после чего нужно сделать рефакторинг. главное - не принебрегайте инкапсуляцией! не просто так это принцип ООП. избегайте магических чисел и переменных в духе x,y. перед рефакторингом ознакомьтесь с SOLID и GRASP, если не слышали об этом. удачи

Comment: огромное спасибо за демонстрацию и советы! Некоторые используемые классы для меня не знакомы, тем интереснее будет это освоить)

Comment: А я могу сделать уточнение в продолжение этой темы?

Comment: @valerjan вы можете задавать вопросы, делать уточнения в комментариях. я постараюсь ответить

Comment: На данный момент я хочу, чтобы моя программа получала информацию из json-файла. Мне удалось реализовать соответствующий метод. На данный момент сложность заключается в том, что я могу работать только с одним выбранным растением. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне каждый раз предлагать пользователю выбирать тип растения?

https://github.com/Valerjan4i4ek/Test/blob/main/Farm

https://github.com/Valerjan4i4ek/Test/blob/main/Game1

https://github.com/Valerjan4i4ek/Test/blob/main/Plant

https://github.com/Valerjan4i4ek/Test/blob/main/json

Comment: Во-первых, исправьте json так, чтобы он содержал массив объектов Plant: [{"name":"Cucumber","seedPrice":10,"harvestPrice":15,"time":5},{"name":"Tomato","seedPrice":20,"harvestPrice":30,"time":3}]

Comment: Во-вторых, я бы использовал для чтения из json файла библиотеку Gson, с ней на много проще работать (по крайней мере в данном случае). Метод для чтения из json будет возвращать массив из всех объектов Plant, которые содержаться в json (дальше делайте с ними, что вам угодно):      public static Plant[] jsonToPlants (String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader(fileName), Plant[].class);
    }

Comment: @valerjan В-третьих, ваш код уже сейчас превращается в треш. Ваш класс Game уже сейчас содержит огромное количество условных операторов с достаточно длинной цепочкой условий. И последнее, не сохраняйте на гите классы по отдельности, сохраняйте проект. Отдельнолежащие классы - плохая идея по очень многим причинам

Comment: 1. Спасибо, исправил
2. Да, так действительно более лаконично и читабельно
3. Я согласен, что он выглядит ужасно. Планировал сделать рефакторинг (по крайней мере постараться) после того, как добьюсь необходимого результата. На счет гита - тоже согласен. еще не разбирался, просто ради удобства туда код загружаю.
К сожалению, моя проблема осталась. После того, как я перебираю массив Plant'ов в методе main и после этого вызываю метод start на объекте Game я могу работать только с тем Plant'ом, который выбрал на первом шаге.Как я могу после посадки вернуться к предыдущему шагу выбора?

Comment: @valerjan при старте игры происходит чтение json, результатом данного чтения является массив Plant. после этого вам нужно создать экземпляр класса Game  и передать в конструктор данный массив. теперь в классе Game  есть поле типа массива Plant. в чем проблема прочитать все либо любое значение из этого массива столько раз, сколько нужно?

Comment: Я вроде бы так и поступаю...
public class Farm {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Plant[] plantList = Game.jsonToPlants("src/plants.json");
        for(Plant plant : plantList){
            new Game(plant, 100, 8).start();
        }
    }
}
но я понимаю, что он останавливается на первом элементе и с ним работает

Comment: @valerjan а вы что ожидаете от такого кода? вы прочитали файл, получили массив, запустили по  нему цикл. на этой строке  new Game(plant, 100, 8).start() вы перешли к выполнению метода start экземпляра класса Game, передав в него нулевой элемент массива. пока этот метод не закончит своего выполнения цикл дальше не пойдет. в чем вопрос то?

Comment: я просто стараюсь передать полученный массив в конструктор экземпляра класса Game. Или мне необходимо переделать сам конструктор и получать в нем не объект, а массив Plant? Но ведь тогда не будут работать геттеры класса Plant. Или я вообще Вас неправильно понял и чтение файла должно происходить в методе start?

Comment: @valerjan чтение файла должно происходить до запуска игры (класса Game), прочитанный массив передаваться в класс Game.

Comment: я создал поле массива Plant в классе Game. Переделал под него конструктор, чтобы при чтении файла можно было передать массив в экземпляр класса Game. В конструкторе циклом прошелся по элементам массива, чтобы поле объекта Plant также было проинициализировано и можно было работать с методами этого класса. Но при этом могу работать только с последним элементом массива. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: 'public Game(Plant[] plantList, int fieldSize, int cash) {
        this.cash = cash;
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.field = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldSize; i++) field.add(SIGN_EMPTY);
        this.plantList = plantList;
        for(Plant p : plantList){
            this.plant = p;
        }
    }'

Comment: @valerjan я вообще не понимаю что вы делаете и что означает "могу работать только с первым/последним элементом массива"? а что происходит с остальными элементами? я отредактировал код в ответе. перенес в класс Game метод main, включая чтнение из джейсона. измените путь к своему джейсону (у меня он в корне проекта). плюс добавл вывод в консоль результаты чтения Plant массива и вывод в консоль элементов данного массива при использовании в игре.

Comment: я хочу добавить возможность выбора конкретного растения по имени до/после выбора поля для посадки. Да подобного результата работы программы я добивался, после чего повторно и обратился сюда.

Comment: @valerjan именно для этого на реальном проекте существуют архитекторы. вы не спроектировали свою игру, а просто начали писать. а когда написали решили, что неплохо бы добавить... либо начали писать с мыслью : 'я потом придумаю, как добавить функционал'. проблема в том, что изначально данное расширение не было продумано, именно поэтому все происходит так мучительно больно. итого извлекаем урок: ставим задачу, проектируем приложение, пишем код. действуем только в такой последовательности. я изменил ответ, разбирайтесь